# Detecting current scaling of page, then resizing to same scaling later?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My WP8 app has a WebBrowser control in which the user can pan and zoom the displayed page till it looks good to him/her.  I would like to capture the current scaling and translation, so I can later show the same page zoomed to the same size.

I have wb.InvokeScript() to invoke arbitrary scripts for me and wb_ScriptNotify() to capture any returned information, but I cannot figure out what properties of what page element to capture.  Standard element.scrollWidth or element.offsetWidth aren't affected by zooming.  I was temporarily excited to read about IE10 properties element.scale, element.translationX and element.translationY, but they are properties of a GestureEvent, not an HTML element like document.documentElement or window.

Can anyone provide some hints?

Comment: The answer is a bit old and does not include IE9, but that's a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that is good enough for now.  It is not pretty.  It works in WP8 with IE10, but I doubt it works for WP7 with the earlier version of IE.

When the user zooms the screen (by pinch guesture) window.outer{Width,Height} are reduced by the zoom factor.  If the window was originally 1024 wide and user zoomed X2, then window.outerWidth is now 512.  And window.page{X,Y}Offset are likewise reduced by the same factor.  However
element sizes (such as document.body.clientWidth) are *not* changed.  So the browser appears to have made the window smaller but left the page alone.  (Come to think of it, that's kind of the definition of zoom...)

But you cannot *set* window.outer{Width,Height} to cause the browser to zoom.  But you can set document.body.style.zoom.  When you do CSS scaling, window.page{X,Y}Offset are not scaled (and neither is window.outer(Width,Height); this is a different, but self-consistent, definition of zoom).

So, to track this:
When page initially loads (before user can zoom),

```
var oldWidth = window.outerWidth;
```

After user finishes manipulating,

```
var newWidth = window.OuterWidth;
var calcZoom = oldWidth / newWidth;
var calcPageXOffset = window.pageXOffset * calcZoom;
var calcPageYOffset = window.pageYOffset * calcZoom;
```

To recreate the scaling and offset when you navigate back to the same URI:

```
document.body.style.zoom = calcZoom;
window.scrollTo( calcPageXOffset, calcPageYOffset);
```